# OutOfMemoryError due to infinite loop because of equals method implementation

Tags: java, equals

I am just trying to understand equals method. I overrode this method in a custom class just to see the behavior but getting out of memory error due to an infinite loop.I know the contract  to override equals method
1) Reflexivity
2) Symmetry
3) Transitive
4) Consistent
5) For any null reference, it must return false

```
public class Reflexivity 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Reflexivity reflexivity = new Reflexivity();
    Reflexivity reflexivity1 = new Reflexivity();
    System.out.println(reflexivity.equals(reflexivity1));
    }
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
     if (!(obj instanceof Reflexivity)) {
            return false;
        }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.equals(obj);
 }
}
```

Comment: your `this.equals(obj)` is causing an infinite loop

Comment: I would just like to point out that you should get a `StackOverflowError` and not an `OutOfMemoryError`.  You will only get an OOME if objects are created.  None are created by your `equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

You implementation is nonsense!

If you have two different `Reflexivity` objects then you are just going to keep calling `equals` forever (or you run out of memory etc).

At some point you actually need to write some code to decide if two objects are equal or not...

Comment: ... and given that he has defined `Reflexivity` with no state, the only two (sane) implementations are "all are equal" and "all distinct instances are are unequal".

Comment: @StephenC I assume it had some state that is not shown here. If not then your right.

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling `equals` method. In lack of any terminating condition, it is resulting in an infinite loop.

Since 1st and 2nd `if` statements returns `false`, it eventually ends up calling itself everytime hence an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `this.equals(obj)` causes the infinit recursiv loop, calling `equals()` again and again. Due to the fact that your class do not hold any state, the behavior of `Object.equals()` is exactly what you need. Hence do not override `equals()` at all.